# iPhone: How do you truncate a float without rounding?

Tags: iphone, floating-point, truncate

I need to simply truncate a floating point number (truncate and not round it).

```
float FloatNum = 43.6823921;
NSString *numString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", FloatNum]; // yields 43.7
```

Comment: He wants 43.6 (not rounding, simply truncating)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can do, but your solution is going to depends on a number of factors.

This will always truncate to the tenths place.

```
float floatNum = 43.6823921;
float truncatedFloat = truncf(floatNum * 10) / 10;
```

As chown mentioned, you can convert it to a string and take the substring. You might want to use `rangeOfString:` os something to find the decimal if you don't always deal with double digit numbers.

Another option would be to use `NSDecimalNumber` with it's method `decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:` to set rounding explicitly. I've used this option a few times to handle currency manipulations where accuracy is very important.

```
float num = 43.6894589;
NSDecimalNumber *decimalNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:num] decimalValue]];
float truncatedFloat = [[decimalNumber decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:self] floatValue];

// NSDecimalNumberBehaviors
- (NSDecimalNumber *)exceptionDuringOperation:(SEL)method error:(NSCalculationError)error leftOperand:(NSDecimalNumber *)leftOperand rightOperand:(NSDecimalNumber *)rightOperand {
    return [NSDecimalNumber notANumber];
}

- (short)scale {
    return 1;
}

- (NSRoundingMode)roundingMode {
    return NSRoundDown;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will convert a float to string, get the substring to index 4, the convert back to a float.  I think this is the usual way of truncating a float without rounding at all:  `float myTruncatedFloat = [[[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:43.6823921] stringValue] substringToIndex:4] floatValue];`.   This will convert `43.6823921` into `43.68`.

```
float myfl = 43.6823921;
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:myfl];
NSString *numStr = [num stringValue];
NSLog(@"%@", numStr);
NSLog(@"%@", [numStr substringToIndex:2]);
NSLog(@"%@", [numStr substringToIndex:3]);
NSLog(@"%@", [numStr substringToIndex:4]);
NSLog(@"%@", [numStr substringToIndex:5]);    
NSLog(@"%@", [numStr substringToIndex:6]);
NSLog(@"%@", [numStr substringToIndex:7]);
NSLog(@"%@", [numStr substringToIndex:8]);
float newMyFloat = [[numStr substringToIndex:4] floatValue];
NSLog(@"%.1f", newMyFloat);
newMyFloat = [[numStr substringToIndex:5] floatValue];
NSLog(@"%.2f", newMyFloat);
```

Prints:

```
[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: 43.68239
[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: 43
[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: 43.
[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: 43.6
[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: 43.68
[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: 43.682
[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: 43.6823
[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: 43.68239
[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: 43.6
[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]: 43.68
```

Comment: That's one way. Is there a way to actually truncate the float itself without rounding?

Comment: This will convert a float to string, get the substring to index 4, the convert back to a float.  I think this is the usual way of truncating a float without rounding at all:  `float myTruncatedFloat = [[[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:43.6823921] stringValue] substringToIndex:4] floatValue];`.   This will convert `43.6823921` into `43.68`.